# SATA Connector for GTP transceivers

Tags: fpga, connector, sata, artix-series-fpga

i have a **Artix7** board with 4 **SATA** connector on it, i want to use these connectors for GTP transceiver, just connectors and i don't want to use SATA protocol, actually i do not know how to write **XDC** file for my SATA connectors, should i change the default xdc file? or the default xdc connects one **tx** to **rx** of other port? do i have to connect **tx** and **rx** myself?

Comment: External or internal transceivers? If they are internal, then look at the datasheet for the FGPA and it will tell you what your options are. If external, look at the schematic for the transievers and which pins they are connected to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transceiver pinout is fixed, so if you want to use them, you are responsible for the physical layer wiring.

Your board documentation should show the pinout but you will probably find yourself needing to make a "Sata" crossover cable of some kind.